# Como obter dados do Banco Mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

Tenho esse trecho de código onde ele pega a informação de um campo do banco de dados e passa para o textBlock, so que agora estou precisando de preencher algumas textblock.

> EX: No banco de datos tem nome=maria Rg=123 cpf=456 ai no programa vai
>   ter as textblock que vão assumir nome, Rg, Cpf.

Codigo:

```
 using (_connection = new MySqlConnection("Database=test;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=teste;SslMode=None;"))
        {
            System.Text.EncodingProvider ppp;
            ppp = System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
            Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);

            _connection.Open();
            var cmd = new MySqlCommand("select name from user where id=1", _connection);
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    textBlock.Text = (reader.GetString("name"));
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: você que por mais esses campos ? na query e nos textBlock

Comment: Eu tenho no banco o campo nome que é assumido pela textblock 1. Soque agora eu adicionei os campos Rg e CPF no banco e que eu quero que seja assumida pela textblock 2 e 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se é o que entendi , basta incrementar os campos na query e nos text.

```
using (_connection = new MySqlConnection("Database=test;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=teste;SslMode=None;"))
{
    System.Text.EncodingProvider ppp;
    ppp = System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
    Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);

    _connection.Open();
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand("select nome, Rg, Cpf from user where id=1", _connection);
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            textBlocknome.Text = (reader.GetString("name"));
            textBlockRg.Text = (reader.GetString("Rg"));
            textBlockCpf .Text = (reader.GetString("Cpf "));
        }
    }
}
```